# how to hide billing information and shipping steps in one page step out

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to hide  billing information and shipping from one page checkout.

Please anybody help me to figure out this solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the below blocks and hide the Billing and shipping methods form one page checkout.

```
 Rewrite class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing
 {
      public function canShip()
     {
        return false;
     }

 }
 Rewrite class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method
 {
     public function isShow()
     {
        return false;
     }
 }
 Rewrite class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping
 {
    public function isShow()
   {
       return false;
   }
 }
```